# Hi. not able to find Text box (element) in Appium even though using al attributes. Error in Appium

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, appium

iam trying to Automate android App. i did use Byxpath, Byid, ByName, By tag. but nothing seems to work. continuously getting  "no such element Found Error". please help me in this.  here is the Code

Code:
package Appium;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;


public class biddingapp_TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
            DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "50f20eb125");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10");
            dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android");
            dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.perennialcode.bidding");
            dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.perennialcode.bidding.MainActivity");
            URL url= new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
            AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver =new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url,dc);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
            // Text Input
            driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@text=\"Mobile No\"]").sendKeys("9700123456");
            
            driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc=\"Continue\"]").click();
        }

    }
```

Error Snapshot

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I can find the error in your image. Can you please paste the text of your error in the question?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Device 50f20eb715 was not in the list of connected devices
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'